# Turn a datalist that gets users from MySQL into Combo Box

Tags: html, mysql, css, forms

I'm using PHP and MySQL to import a list of users into my dropdown box on a form. The user will select their name and move on with the form... my issue at this point is I want to take the drop down box and make a combo box out of it so that the user can quickly type and select there name however I'm not sure of the best way to input that into my php / html code... I'm coming back to this after a couple days away from it so I don't have the code I've tried in the past with a combo box but I could never get it to quite format the names right... what would be the best way to do this?

```
$datalist = "<select id='soflow' name='name'>";
foreach ($stmt as $row) {
  $datalist .= "\r\n<option value='{$row['FULLNAME']}'>{$row['FULLNAME']}</option>";
}
$datalist .= "\r\n</select>";
echo $datalist;

$dbh = null;
?>        
</select><br>
<br></br>
<input type="hidden" name="topicid" value="29">
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Phone Ext"><br>
<input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Title of Request"> <br>
<textarea  placeholder="Put your message here..." cols="50" rows="4" name="message"> </textarea><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="send" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with J Query UI which included a  option inside the ui!